# Python Modules using data in Module Directory

Tags: python, module

I have constructed a Python Module in my own python library directory to share across multiple projects.  However this module uses a datafile from a folder within the module directory to construct a Class of Country Data and their attributes. When time comes to run this module in a project, then the datafile is no longer local as the module is run with reference to the current working directory.

What is the best way to reference data in a python module such that it can be used across projects and the data comes along with the module and hence module object construction?

**Example:**

```
import Classification as cs
codes = cs.Countries()
```

when the `__init__(self)` runs for class Countries, I would like it to reference data within the module directory and not the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to find the directory name of the executable no matter from where the program runs.

if my understanding is right below is the solution

```
import inspect
import os
import sys

def get_current_directory():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    elif __file__:
        application_path = os.path.dirname((inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    return application_path

print get_current_directory()
```